# Weak Convergence and Weak Topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

In discussing weak topology of a normed space $X$, a lemma is given as follows.

> If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ converging weakly to $x$, then $x_n$ is bounded.

I understand the proof of this lemma. My question here is why this lemma is given in the context of weak topology. That is, ***how are weak topology and weak convergence related***? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weak convergence is the convergence with relation to the weak topology.

If $ x_n \in X $ converges weakly to $x $ then $ x $ lies in weak-closure of $ X $.

The weak topology on $ X$ is induced by all sets of the form $ l^{-1}(U) $ where $ l \in X^*$ and $ U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ open.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, please?

Comment: @20824 added more info

Comment: however, note that the converse is not true: if $x$ is in the weak-closure of $A$, then it is not true that there is a *sequence* $x_n \in A$ which converges to $x$ weakly.